# from list<> to database records is repeating

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, ado

I have the following code to create a list<> with three records and populate an access database with this list.  It works but the database is populated with the list's first record three times, i.e., the rows are repeated.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<Project>(){
                new Project{ProjectId="ID1",ProjectName="AAAA"}, 
                new Project{ProjectId="ID2",ProjectName="BBBB"},
                new Project{ProjectId="ID3",ProjectName="CCCC"},
            };


            string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\td\Desktop\Test2.accdb";
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            string accessQuery = "INSERT INTO [table] (ProjectId, ProjectName) VALUES (@ProjectId, @ProjectName)";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(accessQuery, con);

            con.Open();


            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectId", list[i].ProjectId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName", list[i].ProjectName);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }
    }

    public class Project
    {
        public string ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: As in you get the first record three times and you don't get the second and third records at all?

Comment: ID1, AAAA
ID1, AAAA
ID1, AAAA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the command outside your for loop and then attempting to add the parameters to the same command. I am guessing that when you call cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue for i > 0 those values are being silently ignored. Try

```
string accessQuery = "INSERT INTO [table] (ProjectId, ProjectName) VALUES (@ProjectId, @ProjectName)";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(accessQuery, con);    
con.Open();

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectId", list[i].ProjectId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName", list[i].ProjectName);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

If that doesn't work (not at my dev machine, I can't test right now), you can always move the command creation inside your for loop and leave everything else the same.

Comment: You are the man!!! I moved the OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(accessQuery, con); inside the loop and it worked with my previous code.

Comment: Derp, right. Of course Parameters[key] is going to expect an actual OleDbParameter object. Thinking about it more the best option is probably to leave the command outside but call cmd.Parameters.Clear() as the first line inside the for loop.

Comment: That works too.... I spent like 5 hours trying to solve it with no luck.... I don't know how to thank you man.

Comment: Eh, this is proving a distraction from housework. That's good enough for me.